# How we can I assign value to model object key which is an array

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I am using Yii2 with `ActiveFrom`. I have form of user which add multiple names, email etc.

For example:

```
echo $form->field($model, "name[$i]")->widget(kartik\select2\Select2::classname(), [
                                    'data' => $name_master,
                                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select drop down', 'multiple' => false, 'class' => 'selectpicker form-control'],
                                ])->label(false);
```

I am able to save the value at the time of adding it. But when I try to open it in edit form and assign value to model key I am getting error.

Assign value to key for edit mode.

```
foreach ($namesDump as $val) {
    $objectKey = "name";
    $model->$objectKey[$index] = $val['name'];
}
```

It is give me error can someone tell me how we can assign value to object key which is array form.

Comment: why $objectKey = "name";? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use `{}` to indicate precedence for property name - it is different depending on PHP version:

```
$model->{$objectKey}[$index] = $val['name'];
```